# Set the sender of a mail before it is sent in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I use the `Application_ItemSend` event to trigger actions on mails I send.

Under certain conditions the mail shall be moved to a new subfolder.
Since one can't move the mail before it is sent without jeopardizing the send, I copy the mail before sending and delete the original after.

```vb
Set myCopiedItem = objItem.Copy
myCopiedItem.Move olTempFolder
myCopiedItem.UnRead = False
myCopiedItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = olSession.CurrentUser
myCopiedItem.SendUsingAccount = olSession.Accounts(1)
'myCopiedItem.SenderName = olSession.CurrentUser
'myCopiedItem.SenderEmailAddress = olSession.CurrentUser.Address
objItem.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
```

I would like to have me as a sender on the copied mail.

I tried to set several different properties:
`.SendOnBehalfOfName` and `.SendUsingAccount` do not do what I am after.
`.SenderName` and `.SenderEmailAddress` showed to be "read only"

How can I avoid that the mail shows up in the folder without a sender?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

Save the email in the Application_ItemSend event first:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Item.Save
    MoveEmail Item, "\\Mailbox - Darren Bartrup-Cook\Inbox\Some Folder\Some Sub Folder"
End Sub
```

In a separate module (excuse MoveEmail being a function - originally it returned the EmailID of the moved email):

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : MoveEmail
' Author    : Darren Bartrup-Cook
' Date      : 03/07/2015
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function MoveEmail(oItem As Object, sTo As String) As String

    Dim oNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oDestinationFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set oNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oDestinationFolder = GetFolderPath(sTo)

    oItem.Move oDestinationFolder

End Function

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : GetFolderPath
' Author    : Diane Poremsky
' Original  : http://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetFolderPath(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim FoldersArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo GetFolderPath_Error
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If
    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
            Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
            Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
            Set oFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
            If oFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'Return the oFolder
    Set GetFolderPath = oFolder
    Exit Function

GetFolderPath_Error:
    Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `Move` is a function, not a sub - it returns the newly created item. The original must be immediately discarded.

```
set myCopiedItem = myCopiedItem.Move(olTempFolder)
```

Secondly, sender related properties are set only after the message is sent and moved to the Sent Items folder. One solution is to wait until the `Items.ItemAdd` event fires on the Sent Items folder and make a copy then - the sender properties will be set by that time.

In theory, you can set a dozen or so `PR_SENDER_*` and `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_*` MAPI properties, but if I remember my experiments correctly, `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` will not let you set sender related properties. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) is an option (I am its author), it allows to set the `RDOMail.Sender` and `RDOMail.SentOnBehalfOf` properties to an instance of an `RDOAddressEntry` object (such as that returned by `RDOSession.CurrentUser`).